# How to create enterance page in my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to create wordpress enterance page on same url of front page but first show backfround and "entr in the website" button when i click on button so that time site my website with logo menu and frontpage othewise not

look like http://wunderkind.wpengine.com/  this

but my website is multipage in wordpress

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

The template link you have given is a wordpress custom theme and they have used wordpress custom homepage template.

The homepage contains `section` tags which contains background-image and jquery effects for text.

You can use [Genesis sinple page sections](https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-simple-page-sections/) Plugin to create the page sections for home page template.

Or you can do manually by creating the section and then apply css/javascript effects.

Comment: thanks sir, but   if i want write code in header file so it show in all page so what i do ?

Comment: Yes you can write the <section></section> in the header file as well.